# Blackberry XML parsing not working

Tags: blackberry, java-me, xml-parsing

I have following code for parsing

```
public class XML_Parsing_Sample extends UiApplication{

    //creating a member variable for the MainScreen
    MainScreen _screen= new MainScreen();
    //string variables to store the values of the XML document
    String _node,_element;
    Connection _connectionthread;

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        XML_Parsing_Sample application = new XML_Parsing_Sample();
        //create a new instance of the application
        //and start the application on the event thread
        application.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public XML_Parsing_Sample() {
        _screen.setTitle("XML Parsing");//setting title

        _screen.add(new RichTextField("Requesting....."));
        _screen.add(new SeparatorField());
        pushScreen(_screen); // creating a screen
        //creating a connection thread to run in the background
        _connectionthread = new Connection();
        _connectionthread.start();//starting the thread operation
    }

    public void updateField(String node, String element) {

        synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
            String title = "My App";
            _screen.add(new RichTextField(node + " : " + element));

            if (node.equals(title)) {
                _screen.add(new SeparatorField());
            }
            }
    }

    private class Connection extends Thread{

        public Connection(){
            super();
        }

        public void run(){
            // define variables later used for parsing
            Document doc;
            StreamConnection conn;

            try{

                conn=(StreamConnection)Connector.open
                  ("http://www.islamicfinder.org/prayer_service.php?" +
                        "country=united_arab_emirates&city=abu_dhabi&state=01&zipcode=&latitude" +
                        "=24.4667&longitude=54.3667&timezone=4&HanfiShafi=1&pmethod=4&fajrTwilight1=" +
                        "10&fajrTwilight2=10&ishaTwilight=10&ishaInterval=30&dhuhrInterval=1&" +
                        "maghribInterval=1&dayLight=0&simpleFormat=xml&monthly=1&month=");

                _screen.add(new RichTextField("connn---"+conn));
                DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory
                  = DocumentBuilderFactory. newInstance(); 
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder
                  = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                docBuilder.isValidating();
                doc = docBuilder.parse(conn.openInputStream());
                doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
                NodeList list=doc.getElementsByTagName("prayer");
                _node=new String();
                _element = new String();


                for (int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++){
                    Node value=list.item(i).
                      getChildNodes().item(0);
                    _node=list.item(i).getNodeName();
                    _element=value.getNodeValue();
                    updateField(_node,_element);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I am running this application, the simulator is just showing me a Blank screen with label `Requesting..`

Can anybody please help me in doing this? i am using bb9900 simulator.

Comment: try this - String title = "My App";
              _screen.add(new RichTextField(node + " : " + element));
              _screen.invalidate();

Comment: ya i tried it but no changes :(,,

Comment: debug the code and check wether its going to the line  _screen.add(new RichTextField(node + " : " + element));

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple problems I see:

### Changing the UI on the background thread

You are not allowed to directly modify the user interface (UI) from a background thread.  This includes adding `Field` objects to your `Screen`.  But, in your `Connection#run()` method, you do this:

```
 _screen.add(new RichTextField("connn---"+conn));
```

that line will probably throw an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: UI engine accessed without holding the event lock.

and enter your catch handler.  It should be printing out a message, but you might not have noticed it in the Eclipse **Console** window.

I would either move that line out of the `run()` method, and add it to your screen's constructor.  Or, you could make a safe method like this:

```
public void addTextField(final String message) {
   UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          // code in here is run on UI thread, and can safely change the UI
          _screen.add(new RichTextField("connn---"+message));
      }
   });
}
```

Then, from inside `Connection#run()`, call it like this:

```
addTextField(conn.toString());
```

Now, that still may not be what you want.  Printing out a stringified `Connection` object isn't too useful.  Maybe you wanted to print the URL instead?  Anyway, I'll let you decide.

### URL request missing parameter

It looks to me like you're missing a parameter on the end of your URL:

```
"http://www.islamicfinder.org/prayer_service.php?" +
  "country=united_arab_emirates&city=abu_dhabi&state=01&zipcode=&latitude" +
  "=24.4667&longitude=54.3667&timezone=4&HanfiShafi=1&pmethod=4&fajrTwilight1=" +
  "10&fajrTwilight2=10&ishaTwilight=10&ishaInterval=30&dhuhrInterval=1&" +
  "maghribInterval=1&dayLight=0&simpleFormat=xml&monthly=1&month="
```

So, maybe your server needs the month to be appended onto the end of this URL, too.

Try those two things.  That should get your closer.